# occupied place but player changes

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner in python, so I have a problem in the function marker. I would like after the message "The place is occupied!" , game to call player (marker) playing again. In my function if the player gives occupied place, the game calls the other player for playing.

```
def marker(board,marker,position):
    while True:
        if board[position]==" ":
            board[position]=marker
            break    
        else:
            print("The place is occupied!")

        return marker
```

Comment: continue after print statement creates infinite loop

Comment: Is none of your board position set to `" "`? Also let me get this straight. You want the same player to continue right? With different position?

Comment: Yes exactly: the same player take the message "Give another place" for example

Comment: So, you want to call another function which will get the new position? Or is it the calling function that you want to return to? Anyway can you show the code where `marker()` is called and where you are getting the new postion?

Comment: kuro, finally the problem is solved after a combination of your hints. Thanks a lot.